# node.js http(s): get ip address of remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I'm doing https.request({ host: 'domain.com', ... }), how can I get the actual IP address I'm connecting to?

Note that domain.com resolving to multiple IPs and I want to know exactly the IP I'm connecting to.

I tried to get it from socket.remoteAddress:
`req.on('socket', function(socket) { console.log(socket.remoteAddress) })`, but it's undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use `res.connection.remoteAddress`

like this:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get('http://www.google.com', function(res) {
    console.log(res.connection.remoteAddress);
});
```